# how to store html form that contains users countries in sql database

Tags: php, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin, multiple-columns

i am a novice in php but i created this form using html and i want to store it in my sql database i have checked everywhere in internet but i can't find how to store html form that contains users countries,please if anybody can help me create the php source code for this with security, i will be very happy and tell me how to create colume tables for that, thank in advance][1]

[1]:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css" >
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signup.css">
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col col-md-7">
 <form id="frm" method="post">
  
   <img src="img/mm.png">
   <h1>Goldcoin WHITELISTING FORM</h1>
   
   <br>
   <label>First name</label>
   <input type="" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"><br>
   <label>Last name</label>
   <input type="" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"><br>
   <label>Date of birth</label>
   <input type="date" name="" class="form-control"><br>
   <label>Phone Number</label>
   <input type="tel" name="" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control"><br>
   <label>Email Address</label>
   <input type="email" name="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"><br>
   <label>Address</label>
   <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Address1" id="Address1" class="form-control" ><br>
   <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Address1" class="form-control" id="Address2"><br>
   <input type="text" name="" placeholder="City" class="form-control" id="City"><br>
   <input type="text" name="" placeholder="State/Province" class="form-control" id="City"><br>
   <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Postal/Zip" class="form-control" id="City"><br>
   <select class="form-control">
    <option value="">Country</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">
  Afghanistan
 </option>
 <option value="Albania">
  Albania
 </option>
 <option value="Algeria">
  Algeria
 </option>
 <option value="American Samoa">
  American Samoa
 </option>
 <option value="Andorra">
  Andorra
 </option>
 <option value="Angola">
  Angola
 </option>
 <option value="Anguilla">
  Anguilla
 </option>
 <option value="Antarctica" >
  Antarctica
 </option>
 <option value="Antigua and Barbuda" >
  Antigua and Barbuda
 </option>
 <option value="Argentina">
  Argentina
 </option>
 <option value="Armenia">
  Armenia
 </option>
 <option value="Aruba">
  Aruba
 </option>
 <option value="Australia">
  Australia
 </option>
 <option value="Austria">
  Austria
 </option>
 <option value="Azerbaijan">
  Azerbaijan
 </option>
 <option value="Bahamas">
  Bahamas
 </option>
 <option value="Bahrain">
  Bahrain
 </option>
 <option value="Bangladesh">
  Bangladesh
 </option>
 <option value="Barbados">
  Barbados
 </option>
 <option value="Belarus">
  Belarus
 </option>
 <option value="Belgium">
  Belgium
 </option>
 <option value="Belize">
  Belize
 </option>
 <option value="Benin">
  Benin
 </option>
 <option value="Bermuda">
  Bermuda
 </option>
 <option value="Bhutan">
  Bhutan
 </option>
 <option value="Bolivia">
  Bolivia
 </option>
 <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">
  Bosnia and Herzegovina
 </option>
 <option value="Botswana">
  Botswana
 </option>
 <option value="Brazil">
  Brazil
 </option>
 <option value="Brunei Darussalam">
  Brunei Darussalam
 </option>
 <option value="Bulgaria">
  Bulgaria
 </option>
 <option value="Burkina Faso">
  Burkina Faso
 </option>
 <option value="Burundi">
  Burundi
 </option>
 <option value="Cambodia">
  Cambodia
 </option>
 <option value="Cameroon">
  Cameroon
 </option>
 <option value="Canada">
  Canada
 </option>
 <option value="Cape Verde">
  Cape Verde
 </option>
 <option value="Cayman Islands">
  Cayman Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Central African Republic">
  Central African Republic
 </option>
 <option value="Chad">
  Chad
 </option>
 <option value="Chile">
  Chile
 </option>
 <option value="China">
  China
 </option>
 <option value="Christmas Island">
  Christmas Island
 </option>
 <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">
  Cocos (Keeling) Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Colombia">
  Colombia
 </option>
 <option value="Comoros">
  Comoros
 </option>
 <option value="Congo, Republic of(Brazzaville)">
  Congo, Republic of(Brazzaville)
 </option>
 <option value="Cook Islands">
  Cook Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Costa Rica">
  Costa Rica
 </option>
 <option value="Croatia">
  Croatia
 </option>
 <option value="Cuba">
  Cuba
 </option>
 <option value="Cyprus">
  Cyprus
 </option>
 <option value="Czech Republic">
  Czech Republic
 </option>
 <option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo (Kinshasa)">
  Democratic Republic of the Congo (Kinshasa)
 </option>
 <option value="Denmark">
  Denmark
 </option>
 <option value="Djibouti">
  Djibouti
 </option>
 <option value="Dominica">
  Dominica
 </option>
 <option value="Dominican Republic">
  Dominican Republic
 </option>
 <option value="East Timor (Timor-Leste)">
  East Timor (Timor-Leste)
 </option>
 <option value="Ecuador">
  Ecuador
 </option>
 <option value="Egypt">
  Egypt
 </option>
 <option value="El Salvador">
  El Salvador
 </option>
 <option value="Equatorial Guinea">
  Equatorial Guinea
 </option>
 <option value="Eritrea">
  Eritrea
 </option>
 <option value="Estonia">
  Estonia
 </option>
 <option value="Ethiopia">
  Ethiopia
 </option>
 <option value="Falkland Islands">
  Falkland Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Faroe Islands">
  Faroe Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Fiji">
  Fiji
 </option>
 <option value="Finland">
  Finland
 </option>
 <option value="France">
  France
 </option>
 <option value="French Guiana">
  French Guiana
 </option>
 <option value="French Polynesia">
  French Polynesia
 </option>
 <option value="French Southern Territories">
  French Southern Territories
 </option>
 <option value="Gabon">
  Gabon
 </option>
 <option value="Gambia">
  Gambia
 </option>
 <option value="Georgia">
  Georgia
 </option>
 <option value="Germany">
  Germany
 </option>
 <option value="Ghana" id="OPTION_81">
  Ghana
 </option>
 <option value="Gibraltar">
  Gibraltar
 </option>
 <option value="Great Britain">
  Great Britain
 </option>
 <option value="Greece">
  Greece
 </option>
 <option value="Greenland">
  Greenland
 </option>
 <option value="Grenada">
  Grenada
 </option>
 <option value="Guadeloupe" id="OPTION_87">
  Guadeloupe
 </option>
 <option value="Guam" id="OPTION_88">
  Guam
 </option>
 <option value="Guatemala" id="OPTION_89">
  Guatemala
 </option>
 <option value="Guinea" id="OPTION_90">
  Guinea
 </option>
 <option value="Guinea-Bissau" id="OPTION_91">
  Guinea-Bissau
 </option>
 <option value="Guyana" id="OPTION_92">
  Guyana
 </option>
 <option value="Haiti" id="OPTION_93">
  Haiti
 </option>
 <option value="Holy See" id="OPTION_94">
  Holy See
 </option>
 <option value="Honduras" id="OPTION_95">
  Honduras
 </option>
 <option value="Hong Kong" id="OPTION_96">
  Hong Kong
 </option>
 <option value="Hungary" id="OPTION_97">
  Hungary
 </option>
 <option value="Iceland" id="OPTION_98">
  Iceland
 </option>
 <option value="India" id="OPTION_99">
  India
 </option>
 <option value="Indonesia" id="OPTION_100">
  Indonesia
 </option>
 <option value="Iran (Islamic Republic of)" id="OPTION_101">
  Iran (Islamic Republic of)
 </option>
 <option value="Iraq" id="OPTION_102">
  Iraq
 </option>
 <option value="Ireland" id="OPTION_103">
  Ireland
 </option>
 <option value="Israel" id="OPTION_104">
  Israel
 </option>
 <option value="Italy" id="OPTION_105">
  Italy
 </option>
 <option value="Ivory Coast" id="OPTION_106">
  Ivory Coast
 </option>
 <option value="Jamaica" id="OPTION_107">
  Jamaica
 </option>
 <option value="Japan" id="OPTION_108">
  Japan
 </option>
 <option value="Jordan" id="OPTION_109">
  Jordan
 </option>
 <option value="Kazakhstan" id="OPTION_110">
  Kazakhstan
 </option>
 <option value="Kenya" id="OPTION_111">
  Kenya
 </option>
 <option value="Kiribati" id="OPTION_112">
  Kiribati
 </option>
 <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Rep. (North Korea)" id="OPTION_113">
  Korea, Democratic People's Rep. (North Korea)
 </option>
 <option value="Korea, Republic of (South Korea)" id="OPTION_114">
  Korea, Republic of (South Korea)
 </option>
 <option value="Kosovo" id="OPTION_115">
  Kosovo
 </option>
 <option value="Kuwait" id="OPTION_116">
  Kuwait
 </option>
 <option value="Kyrgyzstan" id="OPTION_117">
  Kyrgyzstan
 </option>
 <option value="Lao, People's Democratic Republic" id="OPTION_118">
  Lao, People's Democratic Republic
 </option>
 <option value="Latvia" id="OPTION_119">
  Latvia
 </option>
 <option value="Lebanon" id="OPTION_120">
  Lebanon
 </option>
 <option value="Lesotho" id="OPTION_121">
  Lesotho
 </option>
 <option value="Liberia" id="OPTION_122">
  Liberia
 </option>
 <option value="Libya" id="OPTION_123">
  Libya
 </option>
 <option value="Liechtenstein" id="OPTION_124">
  Liechtenstein
 </option>
 <option value="Lithuania" id="OPTION_125">
  Lithuania
 </option>
 <option value="Luxembourg" id="OPTION_126">
  Luxembourg
 </option>
 <option value="Macau" id="OPTION_127">
  Macau
 </option>
 <option value="Macedonia, Rep. of" id="OPTION_128">
  Macedonia, Rep. of
 </option>
 <option value="Madagascar" id="OPTION_129">
  Madagascar
 </option>
 <option value="Malawi" id="OPTION_130">
  Malawi
 </option>
 <option value="Malaysia" id="OPTION_131">
  Malaysia
 </option>
 <option value="Maldives" id="OPTION_132">
  Maldives
 </option>
 <option value="Mali" id="OPTION_133">
  Mali
 </option>
 <option value="Malta" id="OPTION_134">
  Malta
 </option>
 <option value="Marshall Islands" id="OPTION_135">
  Marshall Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Martinique" id="OPTION_136">
  Martinique
 </option>
 <option value="Mauritania" id="OPTION_137">
  Mauritania
 </option>
 <option value="Mauritius" id="OPTION_138">
  Mauritius
 </option>
 <option value="Mayotte" id="OPTION_139">
  Mayotte
 </option>
 <option value="Mexico" id="OPTION_140">
  Mexico
 </option>
 <option value="Micronesia, Federal States of" id="OPTION_141">
  Micronesia, Federal States of
 </option>
 <option value="Moldova, Republic of" id="OPTION_142">
  Moldova, Republic of
 </option>
 <option value="Monaco" id="OPTION_143">
  Monaco
 </option>
 <option value="Mongolia" id="OPTION_144">
  Mongolia
 </option>
 <option value="Montenegro" id="OPTION_145">
  Montenegro
 </option>
 <option value="Montserrat" id="OPTION_146">
  Montserrat
 </option>
 <option value="Morocco" id="OPTION_147">
  Morocco
 </option>
 <option value="Mozambique" id="OPTION_148">
  Mozambique
 </option>
 <option value="Myanmar, Burma" id="OPTION_149">
  Myanmar, Burma
 </option>
 <option value="Namibia" id="OPTION_150">
  Namibia
 </option>
 <option value="Nauru" id="OPTION_151">
  Nauru
 </option>
 <option value="Nepal" id="OPTION_152">
  Nepal
 </option>
 <option value="Netherlands" id="OPTION_153">
  Netherlands
 </option>
 <option value="Netherlands Antilles" id="OPTION_154">
  Netherlands Antilles
 </option>
 <option value="New Caledonia" id="OPTION_155">
  New Caledonia
 </option>
 <option value="New Zealand" id="OPTION_156">
  New Zealand
 </option>
 <option value="Nicaragua" id="OPTION_157">
  Nicaragua
 </option>
 <option value="Niger" id="OPTION_158">
  Niger
 </option>
 <option value="Nigeria" id="OPTION_159">
  Nigeria
 </option>
 <option value="Niue" id="OPTION_160">
  Niue
 </option>
 <option value="Northern Mariana Islands" id="OPTION_161">
  Northern Mariana Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Norway" id="OPTION_162">
  Norway
 </option>
 <option value="Oman" id="OPTION_163">
  Oman
 </option>
 <option value="Pakistan" id="OPTION_164">
  Pakistan
 </option>
 <option value="Palau" id="OPTION_165">
  Palau
 </option>
 <option value="Palestinian territories" id="OPTION_166">
  Palestinian territories
 </option>
 <option value="Panama" id="OPTION_167">
  Panama
 </option>
 <option value="Papua New Guinea" id="OPTION_168">
  Papua New Guinea
 </option>
 <option value="Paraguay" id="OPTION_169">
  Paraguay
 </option>
 <option value="Peru" id="OPTION_170">
  Peru
 </option>
 <option value="Philippines" id="OPTION_171">
  Philippines
 </option>
 <option value="Pitcairn Island" id="OPTION_172">
  Pitcairn Island
 </option>
 <option value="Poland" id="OPTION_173">
  Poland
 </option>
 <option value="Portugal" id="OPTION_174">
  Portugal
 </option>
 <option value="Puerto Rico" id="OPTION_175">
  Puerto Rico
 </option>
 <option value="Qatar" id="OPTION_176">
  Qatar
 </option>
 <option value="Reunion Island" id="OPTION_177">
  Reunion Island
 </option>
 <option value="Romania" id="OPTION_178">
  Romania
 </option>
 <option value="Russian Federation" id="OPTION_179">
  Russian Federation
 </option>
 <option value="Rwanda" id="OPTION_180">
  Rwanda
 </option>
 <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis" id="OPTION_181">
  Saint Kitts and Nevis
 </option>
 <option value="Saint Lucia" id="OPTION_182">
  Saint Lucia
 </option>
 <option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" id="OPTION_183">
  Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
 </option>
 <option value="Samoa" id="OPTION_184">
  Samoa
 </option>
 <option value="San Marino" id="OPTION_185">
  San Marino
 </option>
 <option value="Sao Tome and Principe" id="OPTION_186">
  Sao Tome and Principe
 </option>
 <option value="Saudi Arabia" id="OPTION_187">
  Saudi Arabia
 </option>
 <option value="Senegal" id="OPTION_188">
  Senegal
 </option>
 <option value="Serbia" id="OPTION_189">
  Serbia
 </option>
 <option value="Seychelles" id="OPTION_190">
  Seychelles
 </option>
 <option value="Sierra Leone" id="OPTION_191">
  Sierra Leone
 </option>
 <option value="Singapore" id="OPTION_192">
  Singapore
 </option>
 <option value="Slovakia (Slovak Republic)" id="OPTION_193">
  Slovakia (Slovak Republic)
 </option>
 <option value="Slovenia" id="OPTION_194">
  Slovenia
 </option>
 <option value="Solomon Islands" id="OPTION_195">
  Solomon Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Somalia" id="OPTION_196">
  Somalia
 </option>
 <option value="South Africa" id="OPTION_197">
  South Africa
 </option>
 <option value="South Sudan" id="OPTION_198">
  South Sudan
 </option>
 <option value="Spain" id="OPTION_199">
  Spain
 </option>
 <option value="Sri Lanka" id="OPTION_200">
  Sri Lanka
 </option>
 <option value="Sudan" id="OPTION_201">
  Sudan
 </option>
 <option value="Suriname" id="OPTION_202">
  Suriname
 </option>
 <option value="Swaziland" id="OPTION_203">
  Swaziland
 </option>
 <option value="Sweden" id="OPTION_204">
  Sweden
 </option>
 <option value="Switzerland" id="OPTION_205">
  Switzerland
 </option>
 <option value="Syria, Syrian Arab Republic" id="OPTION_206">
  Syria, Syrian Arab Republic
 </option>
 <option value="Taiwan (Republic of China)" id="OPTION_207">
  Taiwan (Republic of China)
 </option>
 <option value="Tajikistan" id="OPTION_208">
  Tajikistan
 </option>
 <option value="Tanzania; officially the United Republic of Tanzania" id="OPTION_209">
  Tanzania; officially the United Republic of Tanzania
 </option>
 <option value="Thailand" id="OPTION_210">
  Thailand
 </option>
 <option value="Tibet" id="OPTION_211">
  Tibet
 </option>
 <option value="Timor-Leste (East Timor)" id="OPTION_212">
  Timor-Leste (East Timor)
 </option>
 <option value="Togo" id="OPTION_213">
  Togo
 </option>
 <option value="Tokelau" id="OPTION_214">
  Tokelau
 </option>
 <option value="Tonga" id="OPTION_215">
  Tonga
 </option>
 <option value="Trinidad and Tobago" id="OPTION_216">
  Trinidad and Tobago
 </option>
 <option value="Tunisia" id="OPTION_217">
  Tunisia
 </option>
 <option value="Turkey" id="OPTION_218">
  Turkey
 </option>
 <option value="Turkmenistan" id="OPTION_219">
  Turkmenistan
 </option>
 <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands" id="OPTION_220">
  Turks and Caicos Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Tuvalu" id="OPTION_221">
  Tuvalu
 </option>
 <option value="Uganda" id="OPTION_222">
  Uganda
 </option>
 <option value="Ukraine" id="OPTION_223">
  Ukraine
 </option>
 <option value="United Arab Emirates" id="OPTION_224">
  United Arab Emirates
 </option>
 <option value="United Kingdom" id="OPTION_225">
  United Kingdom
 </option>
 <option value="United States" id="OPTION_226">
  United States
 </option>
 <option value="Uruguay" id="OPTION_227">
  Uruguay
 </option>
 <option value="Uzbekistan" id="OPTION_228">
  Uzbekistan
 </option>
 <option value="Vanuatu" id="OPTION_229">
  Vanuatu
 </option>
 <option value="Vatican City State (Holy See)" id="OPTION_230">
  Vatican City State (Holy See)
 </option>
 <option value="Venezuela">
  Venezuela
 </option>
 <option value="Vietnam">
  Vietnam
 </option>
 <option value="Virgin Islands (British)" id="OPTION_233">
  Virgin Islands (British)
 </option>
 <option value="Virgin Islands (U.S.)" id="OPTION_234">
  Virgin Islands (U.S.)
 </option>
 <option value="Wallis and Futuna Islands" id="OPTION_235">
  Wallis and Futuna Islands
 </option>
 <option value="Western Sahara" id="OPTION_236">
  Western Sahara
 </option>
 <option value="Yemen" id="OPTION_237">
  Yemen
 </option>
 <option value="Zambia" id="OPTION_238">
  Zambia
 </option>
 <option value="Zimbabwe" id="OPTION_239">
  Zimbabwe
 </option>
   </select><br>
   <label>Telegram username (Optional)</label>
   <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Optional"><br>
   <label>Any ERC20 Wallet</label>
   <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Any ERC20 Wallet"><br>
   <label>How Many Ethereum you want to Contribute ?</label>
   <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="Potiential Contribution (ETH)"><br><br><br>
   <label>Gender</label>
   <select class="form-control">
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
   </select><br>
   <h4>I am not a US Citizen</h4><br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="radio" value="" name="group">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="radio" value="" name="group">No
    </label><br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="#bt2">Send Form</button>  
 </form> 
</div>
<div class="col col-md-3"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the steps below you shouldn't have an issue.

1. **Every input needs to have a name** 
   You need to put a name on each input and select in your form like:

   `<input type="" name="first" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">`
2. **Your form need an Action** 
    
   Next, you need to change your form so that it has an action like so:

   `<form id="frm" method="post" action="saveForm.php">`

   After that, you will need a file with the same name as the action. In this case 'saveform.php' the same folder as the page with the form. If you want it in a different folder you can change that using the recitative url.
3. **Establish a database connection and gather your data** 
   next you need to establish a database connection in your php file and get all of the data from the `$_POST[]` variable like so:

   `$firstName = $_POST['name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['last'];`

   The name that you type into the `$_POST[]` variable should match the name you have given to each input element's name.
4. **The value of a select is just text** 
   To get the country from the select element you do exactly the same as above.
   When you store the country into the database, there is nothing special about it. It's just text. So any column in the database that you wish to write the country should be just plain text. Simple as that.

**Update code request**

**Connect to database example: **

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

**Getting Form Variables**

```
$firstName = $_POST["name"];
$lastName = $_POST["last"];
```

**Insert into Database**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name (firstName,lastName,...) VALUES (".$firstName.",".$lastName.",...)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Added some example code. On connecting to database and getting form variables. If you want me to write the entire thing for you this is the wrong site and while I don't mind helping, I prefer not to do other peoples work unless I'm getting paid. A quick Google search should get you any thing else you need to know.